# Can't find jar file for imports

Tags: java, jar

Hi I have the following imports:

```
import org.hyperic.hq.measurement.UnitsConvert;
import org.hyperic.hq.product.MeasurementInfo;
import org.hyperic.hq.product.MeasurementPlugin;
import org.hyperic.hq.product.MeasurementPluginManager;
import org.hyperic.hq.product.MetricValue;
import org.hyperic.hq.product.PluginNotFoundException;
import org.hyperic.hq.product.ProductPlugin;
import org.hyperic.hq.product.ProductPluginManager;
import org.hyperic.hq.product.TypeInfo;
import org.hyperic.util.config.ConfigResponse;
import org.hyperic.util.units.FormattedNumber;
```

It says cannot resolve symbol **hq** because I don't have the required jar file.

I have searched over the internet, but could not find the jar file. I have been trying for quite a long time but with no success, the thing which I found similar is [hyperic/hq](https://github.com/hyperic/hq) but how can I get the jar file or the maven repository from this?

Somebody please help me. Any directions would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Surely it is in a maven nexus

Comment: from where did you know you have to import the above imports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the settings from a pivotal project:

> https://github.com/pivotal/tcs-hq-product-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml

It contains the list repositories:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>hyperic-external</id>
    <name>Hyperic External Repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.cm.hyperic.org/external</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>hyperic-milestone</id>
    <name>Hyperic Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.cm.hyperic.org/milestone</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>hyperic-release</id>
    <name>Hyperic Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.cm.hyperic.org/release</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>private-springsource-external</id>
    <name>Private Springsource External Repository</name>
    <url>http://private.maven.springsource.com/external</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

I compared with https://github.com/hyperic/hq and did a minor modification (already modified above) : `maven.hyperic.org/...` =­­> `maven.cm.hyperic.org/...`

this works:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hyperic.hq</groupId>
    <artifactId>hq-util</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hyperic.hq</groupId>
    <artifactId>hq-common</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**I did an artifact search on these repos (using my IDE), and it listed only 2 versions for hq-common: `4.5.0.M6` and `4.6.5`**

The other option you have, is to clone the code from github (https://github.com/hyperic/hq) and build it locally.
Then, you'll be able to use the latest version.